# How to play a local video in a Qt Widgets Application, in Qt creator?

Tags: c++, qt, video, widget, qt-creator

This is probably a very noob question... I am very new to Qt, and trying programming in Qt creator. Now I created a new Qt Widgets Application from Qt creator, and want to play a video with it. I now have the following 6 files in my project:

- Project

  - Project.pro
  - Headers

    - videoplayer.h
  - Sources

    - main.cpp
    - videoplayer.cpp
  - Forms

    - videoplayer.ui
  - Other files

    - /Users/somebody/somewhere

      - Demo.mp4

Where and how exactly should I write my code to make it play Demo.mp4 when I run my application (maybe using some tools called QVideoPlayer)? Should I add some Qwidget onto my videoplayer.ui? I now have four buttons "play", "pause", "full_screen" and "rearrange" on my videoplayer.ui. The result I want is something with features of:

- Press play button to play Demo.mp4 on the top-left of the entire window
- Press Pause to pause
- Press full_screen to enter full screen (if QMediaPlayer can enter/quit full screen itself, then this feature is not necessary)
- press rearrange to put the playing window from top-left to top-right
- additional: fast forward and rewind (again, if QVideoPlayer or something Qt provided not already has this feature)

Comment: Qt ships with examples of video players, that would be a good starting place.  They're also online here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/multimedia-examples.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for *Qt Multimedia Widgets*. (You might need to install extra packages when running Linux).

The basic idea goes like this:

- On the UI side of things you use a [`QVideoWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvideowidget.html). This is where the video is displayed.

  - This is what you would add to your `.ui` file.
  - Note the `fullScreen` property.
- On the logic side of things you use a [`QMediaPlayer`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html) which controls what is played and when it's played.

  - The two are connected by calling `QMediaPlayer::setVideoOutput(yourVideoWidgetGoesHere);`.
  - Then you add a [`QMediaPlaylist`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmediaplaylist.html) to your `QMediaPlayer`.
  - Finally call `QMediaPlayer::play()` and you should be good to go

Then you want some basic controls if this works so far. `QMediaPlayer` provides the following slots that exactly do as their names suggest:

- `pause()`
- `play()`
- `stop()`
- `setPosition(int)`, argument is in milliseconds. `duration()` might be of interest.
- `setVolume(int)` and `setMuted(bool)`. Volume goes from 0 to 100.
- `setPlaybackRate(double)`
- Metadata is available via `metaData(QString key)`: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmediaobject.html#metaData

Each of these also has a corresponding change signal, very interesting for you is probably the `positionChanged(int)` signal to update a slider or something similar with the current position.

Basic example courtesy of the Qt documentation:

```
player = new QMediaPlayer;

playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(player);
playlist->addMedia(QUrl("http://example.com/myclip1.mp4"));
playlist->addMedia(QUrl("http://example.com/myclip2.mp4"));

videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);

videoWidget->show();
playlist->setCurrentIndex(1);
player->play();
```

Comment: I can't find `QVideoWidget` in the UI Designer. I found this answer but don't know which widget to use (You can insert a normal widget in Qt Designer and then promote it to `QVideoWidget`)

Comment: I believe there should be a creator/designer plugin to add these. Alternatively promotion is an easy way to get it done, as you say.

Comment: would you please take a look at my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41213837/play-a-video-using-qt-5-7-and-visual-studio-2015?noredirect=1#comment69626626_41213837

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is to implement a [QMediaPlayer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html) if you are on `Qt 5`, a [QVideoPlayer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-videoplayer.html) if you are on `Qt 4.4`

For `QMediaPlayer`, you'll have to use a following implementation for adding one movie :

```
QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;
player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/users/somebody/somewhere/demo.mp4"));
player->setVolume(10);
player->play();
```